# Awk gsub replacement concatenation

Tags: linux, shell, awk

I have a file with the following:

```
>NODE_1_length_281510_cov_20.148788
CGTCGAGACAACCAAGAAGCACGGCAACTCGCCCTACAACGCAATCCTCGCCCTTCTCTA
```

I want to sub in a variable between the > and NODE to get

```
>variable_NODE_1_length_281510_cov_20.148788
CGTCGAGACAACCAAGAAGCACGGCAACTCGCCCTACAACGCAATCCTCGCCCTTCTCTA
```

Is it possible to do something like the following with gsub in awk? $foo is the variable.

```
  awk -v a="$foo" '{if(!/>NODE/){print; next}; gsub("NODE",a,$1);print}' "$file">> "${foo}.fasta"
```

I'm not getting any error. The script is just getting stuck. I know my solution will only replace the word NODE with the directory name. Is it possible to do concatenation inside gsub?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

example with `awk` using sub()

```
bar=par_dir_name
awk -v pdir="$bar" '{ sub("^>NODE",pdir "_NODE"); print }' infile >> "${bar}.fasta"
```

example with gnu `awk` gensub()

```
bar=par_dir_name
awk -v pdir="$bar" '{ print gensub("^>NODE",pdir "_NODE",1) }' infile >> "${bar}.fasta"
```

simpler possible alternate:

```
bar=par_dir_name
sed "s/^>NODE/>${bar}_NODE/" infile >> "${bar}".fasta
```

Comment: That's fragile in a couple ways. Try those scripts with `bar='this&that'` or `bar='this\that'` or `bar='this\1that'`, or `bar='this\\\0that'` etc.

Answer (score 2):

Don't use *sub() with the directory name as either argument or you have to introduce handling for metacharacters that might be in  the directory name. Just treat the directory name as a string, e.g. run from `/home/Ed/tmp`:

```
$ awk 'sub(/^>/,""){$0=">" ENVIRON["PWD"] "_" $0} 1' file
>/home/Ed/tmp_NODE_1_length_281510_cov_20.148788
CGTCGAGACAACCAAGAAGCACGGCAACTCGCCCTACAACGCAATCCTCGCCCTTCTCTA
```

or:

```
$ awk -v dir="$PWD" 'sub(/^>/,""){$0=">" dir "_" $0} 1' file
>/home/Ed/tmp_NODE_1_length_281510_cov_20.148788
CGTCGAGACAACCAAGAAGCACGGCAACTCGCCCTACAACGCAATCCTCGCCCTTCTCTA
```

or if your directory names can contain backslashes and you want to use a user-defined variable then:

```
$ dir="$PWD" awk 'sub(/^>/,""){$0=">" ENVIRON["dir"] "_" $0} 1' file
>/home/Ed/tmp_NODE_1_length_281510_cov_20.148788
CGTCGAGACAACCAAGAAGCACGGCAACTCGCCCTACAACGCAATCCTCGCCCTTCTCTA
```

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 it's part of POSIX so it's common to all awks that are at least POSIX compliant. See https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/awk.html.

Comment: This is great, unfortunately my file path is very long and I can only have 50 characters in that first line.

Comment: @skiventist what does the length of line have to do with my solution vs any other solution? How do you want longer lines handled - truncated from the front, from the back or something else? Please [edit] your question to include those details/requirements.

Comment: @EdMorton Updated! My bad. Might need your help in the future Sir.

Comment: I still don't see how what I showed doesn't solve your problem (and do it more robustly than your currently accepted answer) but OK, no worries.